# Filter Criteria Only Getting First Value In Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a list on worksheet3 of values, that I then build an array from (strArray)

```
' ADDS ALL ROWS FROM SHEET3 TO A ARRAY
With Worksheets(3)
TotalRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strArray = .Range("A1:A" & TotalRows).Value
MsgBox UBound(strArray)
'Debug.Print Join(strArray, ", ")
End With
```

After this I am then trying to filter my data using the following code:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    .Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1")
End With
```

What happens is that it only filters for the first value in the array. However, if I change **strArray** to **array("test", "test")** for example, it works fine and builds criteria based on all the values in the array.

Why is this occurring?

Full code:

```
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

' ADDS ALL ROWS FROM SHEET3 TO A ARRAY
With Worksheets(3)
TotalRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strArray = .Range("A1:A" & TotalRows).Value
MsgBox UBound(strArray)
'Debug.Print Join(strArray, ", ")
End With


With Worksheets(1)
    .Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: try this: `Criteria1:=application.transpose(strArray)`

Comment: Such an easy fix - thanks so much